# Use sun.* classes in Eclipse Java project

Tags: java, eclipse, build-process

I was sent some Java code that uses classes in the `sun.awt.shell` package, which is not part of the JDK public API, so Eclipse will not compile the project:

> Access restriction: The method getIcon(boolean) from the type ShellFolder is not accessible due to restriction on required library /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Classes/classes.jar

While I agree with the sentiment, can I coerce Eclipse to compile it anyway?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings`, find the "Deprecated and restricted API section", and change the "Forbidden reference" setting from Error to Warning or Ignore.